# Adding input arguments to method nodes in OPCUA (OPCFoundation) .Net

Tags: .net, opc-ua

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I can't figure out how to call a method node's method with input arguments. Doing this throws a 'badtoomanyarguments' exception.

```
Session.Call(new NodeId(2001, 2), new NodeId(2012, 2), new Variant(""))
```

Likewise, when using UAExpert to call a method there is no possibility for me to add input arguments.
I assume it is possible to specify somewhere the number of input arguments a method node expects? Something like:

```
myMethodNode.inputArguments += NodeId[];
myMethodNode.inputArguments += string;
```

In documentation and online examples I've only managed to find examples where a method node is called without arguments, hence this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You should find a Node named "InputArguments" (and another one OutputArguments) under you Method Node.

Check the value of this Node, it will help you understand what are the parameters you need to give.

Here an example with the GetMonitoredItems Method Node which is taking 1 parameter (Array[1]) as InputArguments and it should be a NodeId

[image: OPC UA Method Input Arguments Node]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can figure it out from there.
The link you sent doesn't work though

Comment: Nvm link does work